# Proving the quadratic form over $x'x$ is in between eigenvalues with Schur's decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \le ....\le \lambda_n$. I need apply Schur's decomposition to prove that

$$
\lambda_1 \le \frac{x'Ax}{x'x} \le \lambda_n.
$$

I'm really not sure how to get started on this one. I know that $S'AS = \Lambda$ where the column vectors of $S$ are eigenvectors, and $\Lambda$ has the eigenvalues on the diagonal. I just don't see what transformations I could apply to create anything usable.

Comment: Are you sure that you're supposed to use the Schur decomposition? Perhaps you are meant to use [Schur's majorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem) instead

Comment: Also, does $A$ necessarily have real number entrires?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is symmetric real then there is an orthogonal $Q$ such that $Q^TAQ= \Lambda=\operatorname{diag}\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\}$.

Then $x^TAx = (Qx)^T \Lambda (Qx)=\sum_k \lambda_k [Qx]_k^2\le \lambda_n \sum_k [Qx]_k^2 = \lambda_n x^T x$
with a corresponding bound for $\lambda_1$.